# identifier is undefined when setting default value?

Tags: c++

I have a header file that looks like this:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class FileAccessMode
{
    Read = 0,
    Write,
    ReadWrite
};

void OpenFile(const char* cpcFile, FileAccessMode eFileAccessMode);
```

This code is given by our professor.

The function `OpenFile()` will not be implemented, how do I suppress warnings with `_CRT_UNUSED`?

Also, I want to set the default value for `FileAccessMode` to `ReadWrite`. On instinct, I just tried:

```cpp
eFileAccessMode = 2
```

and

```cpp
eFileAccessMode = ReadWrite
```

For the first attempt, it says:

> default argument of type int is incompatible with parameter of type FileAccessMode

For the latter, it says:

> identifier ReadWrite is undefined

What's my problem here?

Comment: I believe you need `eFileAccessMode = FileAccessMode::ReadWrite`.

Comment: AFAIK, `_CRT_UNUSED()` only applies to variables, not to functions. If you declare a function but never implement it or try to call it, the compiler should just optimize it away